# How to preserve .d files after kernel compilation?

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules

I'm compiling third-party kernel modules. Their build system goes to `/usr/src/linux-headers-[version]` (of a custom kernel chroot) and runs `make` from there.

I want to find out, which files - sources and headers - have been used for the compilation, and which have not. Standard `scripts/Makefile.build` creates `*.d` files for each compiled source, and I'd like to use that... but these files are **deleted** after short processing. (That is `rule_cc_o_c` definition in `Makefile.build`.)

What could be a way to collect these files with minimal modifications to the standard build system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [libtrashcan](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~marriaga/software/libtrash/). After compiling it and installing, preload the library to your process.

For example, the following will create a test file and then try to remove it, but because of libtrashcan the `unlink` system call will be replaced by a move, so the file will end up in `~/Trash`:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libtrash.so.3.3
touch testfile
rm testfile
```